# create transparent PNG for GTK 2.0

Tags: graphics, pidgin, gtk

Im trying to create a transparent theme for pidgin in windows, which uses gtk 2.0. I simply grabbed a theme dropped opacity and saved it again, however that didn't seem to work too well. How do i create a proper transparency for GTK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set it in the Alpha channel.  http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter04.html